# Why am I getting Unknown column in field list?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

When I run this command, I get the `Unknown column 'Orders' in 'field list'`

I am trying to get customer list with number of orders, and a new column for type. If the customer has more than 10 orders. It is a big buyer etc.

```
 SELECT 
    customerTable.isActive,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            orderTable
        WHERE
            orderTable.customerId = customerTable.id) AS Orders,
    
    CASE
        WHEN Orders > 10 THEN 'Big buyer'
        WHEN Orders > 12 THEN 'Biggest buyer'
    END AS 'Type'
   
    FROM customerTable
```

Also what is the correct term when you use select in the column section of my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

```
SELECT 
    customerTable.isActive,
    @Orders := (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM orderTable
                WHERE orderTable.customerId = customerTable.id) AS Orders,
    CASE
        WHEN @Orders > 10 THEN 'Big buyer'
        WHEN @Orders > 12 THEN 'Biggest buyer'
    END AS 'Type'
FROM customerTable;
```

The `SELECT` in the column list is just considered a subquery.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer. I guess sub queries have to be stored in a variable before they can be referenced.  Can not reference a subquery by an alias.

Comment: Yes, but I believe this behavior is restricted to subqueries in the column list. A subquery in the `FROM` clause has to have an alias and there is no issue when referencing it.